# Erro ao abrir aplicativo com process.start

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Tenho um aplicativo que ao tentar executar com o `process.start` ou até mesmo direto pelo `cmd` do Windows, não inicia corretamente (o aplicativo em si apresenta erro), porém se eu for na pasta dele e abrir o executável, ele abre corretamente.

Dentro da pasta do aplicativo, só existe ele e um arquivo de parâmetros `.ini`,
estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
private void button_abrirr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntegradorTEF-IP\IntegradorTEF-IP.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falha ao abrir arquivo!\n\n");
        }
    }
```

Eu acredito que talvez o erro seja porque ele não puxe esse arquivo `.ini`,
alguém conhece alguma outra forma de tentar abrir o aplicativo via *prompt* de comando ou pelo C#?

Comment: Post o seu código de como você está chamando o Process.Start(), pode ser um erro no caminho.

Comment: editei na pergunta, mas o caminho está correto, visto que ele tenta abrir o aplicativo e a mensagem de erro que ocorre é do próprio aplicativo aberto. Outros aplicativos estão abrindo normalmente, geralmente são esses aplicativos com arquivos .ini que não dão certo.

Comment: O que é "ir na pasta"? porque pelo `cmd` você deve estar indo na pasta. Não faz muito sentido executar em no Windows/File Explorar e não funcionar no  `cmd`.

Comment: É abrir a pasta onde está localizado o aplicativo e abrir ele com o duplo clique do mouse mesmo. Pelo CMD eu coloco o caminho, ele abre mas o aplicativo informa erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente o executável só funciona se for chamado na pasta onde ele está, o que é uma falha, mas para resolver isso deve chamá-lo na pasta ao invés do caminho absoluto. Para isso é preciso iniciar o processo com informações mais completas sobre o que será executado, como a pasta onde ele se encontra. Isso é efeito com a classe [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IntegradorTEF-IP.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntegradorTEF-IP";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/StartProcess.cs).

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: vlw a dica, já marquei aqui!

Comment: @Maniero - Muito obrigado! Fiz um app pra monitorar uma aplicação externa. Precisava iniciar um programa programaticamente, e por `Process.Start(...)` o programa dava um erro sem sentido. Com o código proposto, funcionou perfeitamente!